# How do I enable port security on Cisco switch?

Tags: cisco, switch, switching, cisco-catalyst, switchport

I have a Cisco switch model 3500 series 48 port. I need to enable port security on this switch. Could you tell me the configuration commands to apply this policy?

Comment: OK, then enable it. Do you have an actual question, or are you simply making an announcement?

Comment: Dear I want a configuration command for this

Comment: You should edit your question to ask what you want.

Comment: Sorry, i  edit it

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and explain. . I got the point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enabling port security is extremely easy at its core. It gets more complicated with the options.

Enabling port security on a switch port is done with a simple command: `switchport port-security`

Cisco maintains [documentation](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/12-2/25ew/configuration/guide/conf/port_sec.html) on its commands.

Comment: Thanks ,but when i need apply this policy on all ports on switch what can i do ??

Comment: This is enabled on the ports individually. You don't want to do this on trunk ports, for example, only on access ports. You could use the `interface range` macro command to apply it to multiple ports at once.

Comment: if i don't know all mac address for PC's connected to the switches?

Comment: You don't need to know the MAC addresses for most options. MAC address restrictions are pretty bad because anyone can easily clone a MAC address. Maybe you should start another question that asks about what you are trying to achieve by using port security. There may be other, better ways to accomplish it.

Comment: just i need apply security ports on all switches i have but i don't have all mac add for these PC's connected to switches ?? no need to know all mac add foe these PC's right to apply port security command ?!!

Comment: That depends on what options you use. Normally, no, you don't need a MAC address. You can let the port learn and remember the MAC address the first time the device connects. That is sticky port security.

Answer (score 0):

In cisco environment there is feasiblity to configure authentication for ports .

If users wants to use specific ports , then users has to validate with credentials

Switch1(config)#interface fa0/1
Switch1(config-if)#switchport port-security
Switch1(config-if)#switchport port-security maximum 1